# .NET Core get connection string from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I develop a simple web app and, in the future, I want to do it as multi-tenancy.

So I want to write the connection string straight into `OnConfiguring` method:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connection string from appsettings.json");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

How can I extract connection string from `appsettings.json` into `ApplicationContext` class?

I wouldn't like to create any constructors for `ApplicationContext` class.

Comment: You need to pass the connection string as parameter to AddDbContext IIRC

Comment: Why do you want to register it the `OnConfiguring` method rather than within `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("..."))`?

Comment: @Tseng I need to change dynamically connection strings in future for multi-tenancy.

Comment: @A.Gladkiy Are you going to dynamically change the connection string of an in-use context? Sounds like a bad idea. Why not just register the context multiple times?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I want to create db each time after user was registered. What do you mean by register context multiple times?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm not 100% sure how will it look like, but I would be glad if you give me a link with good implementation of multi-tenancy + .Net Core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I want to write the connection string straight into OnConfiguring method:
>
> How can I extract connection string from appsettings.json into ApplicationContext class?
>
> I wouldn't like to create any constructors for ApplicationContext class.

You could use **Options Pattern** via `IOptions` but the easiest way is using DI in `ApplicationContext` constructor ;)

Follow below articles, please:

- [Example of using IOptions](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/2fa.html#setup-up-sms-for-two-factor-authentication-with-twilio),
- [Using Options and configuration objects](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#options-config-objects),
- [IOptions Interface](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/Extensions/Options/IOptions-TOptions/index.html?highlight=IOptions),

Answer (score 23):

Let's imagine that you have **.NET Core** application and your `appsettings.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Production": {
    "SqliteConnectionString": "Filename=./MyDatabase.sqlite"
  }
}
```

You can get `SqliteConnectionString` value from `Startup.cs` like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection = Configuration["Production:SqliteConnectionString"];

    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(connection)
    );
    ....
 }
```

And then in your `DBContext` you should add constructor that accepts `DbContextOptions`:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext (DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    ...
}
```

Comment: It's good. But how can I get the same string into `ApplicationContext` class? I can't do it as you wrote.

Comment: And what if I want to use parameterless constructor for `MyContext`?

Answer (score 11):

**.NET Core 2.0**

Add this class:

```
// Requires NuGet package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace RutarBackgroundServices.AppsettingsJson
{
    public static class AppSettingsJson
    {
        public static string ApplicationExeDirectory()
        {
            var location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            var appRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(location);

            return appRoot;
        }

        public static IConfigurationRoot GetAppSettings()
        {
            string applicationExeDirectory = ApplicationExeDirectory();

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(applicationExeDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            return builder.Build();
        }


    }
}
```

Get the value for the key "MssqlConnectionString" from the "appsettings.json" file:

```
var appSettingsJson = AppSettingsJson.GetAppSettings();
var connectionString = appSettingsJson["MssqlConnectionString"];
```

Create the file "appsettings.json" in the root directory of your project:

```
{
  "MssqlConnectionString": "Server=yourip; Database=yourdbname; User Id=yourusername; Password=yourpassword; Pooling=true;",
  "Db2ConnectionString": "Database=yourdbname;UserID=yourusername;Password=yourpassword;Server=yourip:yourport",
  "SomeOtherKey": "SomeOtherValue"
}
```

Comment: I used this for this same issue in a .NET Core 2 app and it's perfect. Highly recommend.

Comment: Better to use the "ConnectionStrings" section as in:
{
     "ConnectionStrings": {
         "MssqlConnectionString": "Server=yourip; Database=yourdbname; User Id=yourusername; Password=yourpassword; Pooling=true;",
          "Db2ConnectionString": "Database=yourdbname;UserID=yourusername;Password=yourpassword;Server=yourip:yourport",
     },
       "SomeOtherKey": "SomeOtherValue"}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the factory pattern to resolve your `DbContext`.

```
public interface ITenantDbContextFactory
{
    ApplicationContext Create(string tenantId);
}

public class TenantDbContextFactory()
{
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public TenantDbContextFactory()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationContext Create(string tenantId) 
    {
        if(this.context==null) 
        {
            var connectionString = GetConnectionForTenant(tenantId);
            var dbContextBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
            dbContextBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            this.context = new ApplicationContext(dbContextBuilder);
        }

        return this.context;
    }
}
```

In Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>();
services.AddScoped<ITenantDbContextFactory, TenantDbContextFactory>();
```

Your service or controller:

```
public class HomeController 
{
    private readonly ITenantDbContextFactory dbFactory;
    public HomeControler(ITenantDbContextFactory tenantDbContextFactory)
    {
        this.dbFactory = tenantDbContextFactory;
    }

    public void Action()
    {
        var dbContext = this.dbFactory.Create("tenantA");
        // use your context here
        dbContext...
    }
}
```