# How to get ConnectionString in a ClassLibrary?

Tags: asp.net-core, connection-string, .net-core

Connection strings exist in `appsettings.json` in an ASP.Net MVC Core Project. I also have a Class Library Project in the same solution and there I want to get the connection string of web project, I am unable to find help in official resources, how can I achieve this?

Update: The class library is of .Net 4.6.1, also in the ASP.Net Core Project I am targeting .Net 4.6.1.

Comment: Add reference `System.Configuration` in your Class library project.

Comment: Please have a look at [Get connection string in class library project in a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682078/get-connection-string-in-class-library-project-in-a-solution)

Comment: @Abhay
Sure. Thanks.

Comment: @Abhay: Don't ignore the tags. Question is about ASP.NET Core, which doesn't support confiugration via web.config anymore. One should use the dependency injection pattern all the way and the `IOptions<T>`pattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core get connection string from appsettings.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218850/net-core-get-connection-string-from-appsettings-json)

Comment: My advice is to use the context as a dependency , register your dependency in the startup.cs or Used a IOC repo pattern

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet of your solution?

Answer (score 2):

Register `Configuration` in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServicesCollection services) 
{
     services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
}
```

Then you can inject it in controller or any other library project class

```
public HomeController(IConfigurationRoot Configuration)
{
            this.Configuration= Configuration;
}
```

Then you can get connection string as you get in `Startup.cs`

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
```